# Liferay - Translate

Tags: menu, liferay, translation, addition

I am using Liferay 6.1.0 GA1.

I added Documents and Media portlet. When I change language in Add menu, it is still named Documents and Media display.

Where I can change that?

Edit: I have hook for translations I just don't know what to write to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As excepcted for rookie, problem was trivial.

In portlet.xml name wasn't documents-and-media. It was some number.
So then just javax.portlet.title.1= fixed it.

If You don't have a hook, look there - 
https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins
https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5368654

Comment: You should consider also donating your translation to Liferay at http://translate.liferay.com as while you are at it.